# Create Linq Expression<Func<TModel, TDataType>> for the given property name

Tags: linq, .net-core, expression

How do I create the proper Linq expression for the following property with navigation: `m.Model.Property1`?

I have a model like this:

```
public class ViewModel
{
   public object Model { get; set; } //=Model is acutally the EntityModel
}
public class EntityModel
{
  public string Property1
}
```

I have now something like this but can't find the Property1.
For the 2 last lines below I can't find a proper solution to get this, so I can send it to the HtmlHelper

```
var parameter = Expression.Parameter(typeof(ViewModel), "m"); //=ViewModel

var baseType = Html.ViewData.Model.GetType(); //=typeof(ViewModel)
var navExpr = Expression.Convert(Expression.Property(parameter, "Model"), typeof(EntityModel));

var exprProp = Expression.Property(navExpr , "Property1"); //This should create {m.Model.Property1}
var navExpr2 = Expression.Convert(exprProp, typeof(object));

return Expression.Lambda<Func<EditViewModel, object>>(navExpr2, parameter);
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to convert object to `EntityModel`. This can be achieved with `Expression.Convert`. Try changing your `navExpr` to this:

```
var navExpr = Expression.Convert(Expression.Property(parameter, "Model"), typeof(EntityModel));
```

In your code sample in question `Property1` is actually a field, not a property (you can use `Expression.PropertyOrField` or `Expression.Field` if it is so).

Comment: @2501279 / guru-stron Tnx, that solves the Model conversion part. 
I solved the second part by adding the navExpr2 as convert to object. It comes in the MyHtmlHelper class, then I need to get the property name out of the expression again.
When I give the incomming expression to the HtmlHelper.TextBoxFor(expression, attrs) it failes: "Templates can be used only with field access, property access, single-dimension array index, or single-parameter custom indexer expressions"; So I made it a TextBox(fullPropertyName, value, attrs) which works. But I don't like its done. I prefer the TextBoxFor.

Comment: @Christiaan it seems that this is limitation of `HtmlHelper`. `TextBoxFor` can access only "simple" selectors. What actually you wanted to achieve?